# DoPostBack call javascript in load() jquery function

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net, web

I have a doPostBack call inside a .load() jquery function.
After the function run, the web page will refresh and it creates an infinite loop.
How can I manage this situation?

```
$("#id").load(function(){ 
   //code
   DoPostBack(...)
}
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: Maybe don't POST your page?  You could use an ajax POST rather than a form POST.  Alternatively, add a hidden input that you check/set in the .load - it will be preserved over the postback.

Answer (score 0):

To refresh a page once each time it opens use:

```
<head>
 <META HTTP-EQUIV="Pragma" CONTENT="no-cache">
 <META HTTP-EQUIV="Expires" CONTENT="-1">
</head>
```

If you need to do it via pure JS. You can use local storage base solution